# [meteor][0.6.*] error with package.js : module is not defined

Tags: meteor

i try to deploy my meteor application, but it still fail. I use meteor 0.6.1, and its package system.
in my root app, i created the following file tree :

```
packages
    cheerio
        package.js
    iconv-lite
        package.js
```

here is the content of the package.js :

```
Package.describe({
    summary: 'Cheerio, an html parser with Jquery like API, but server side'
});

Npm.depends({cheerio: '0.10.8'});
```

and

```
Package.describe({
    summary: 'Encoding management'
});

Npm.depends({'iconv-lite': '0.2.7'});
```

Then i do a meteor deploy appName, and then a meteor logs appName
and here is the error :

```
[Tue Apr 09 2013 13:14:59 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO ReferenceError: module is not defined
at app/packages/cheerio/index.js:5:11
at /meteor/containers/72e47bd9-1446-3b0f-126d-113dfb566c3c/bundle/server/server.js:282:7
at Array.forEach (native)
at Function._.each._.forEach (/meteor/dev_bundles/0.3.0/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
at run (/meteor/containers/72e47bd9-1446-3b0f-126d-113dfb566c3c/bundle/server/server.js:227:7)
```

So i get a problem because the var `module` is not defined in the js file.
I don't know what to do, and any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Here is an article that bring a great sample that works :

[meteor-npm-integration](http://www.armetiz.info/meteor-npm-integration/) !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this website: [meteor-npm-integration](http://www.armetiz.info/meteor-npm-integration/), i wrote a little subject to explain a little bit more the system of meteor Npm package: [tumblr](http://rebolon.tumblr.com/post/47618181073/meteor-npm-package-how-to-do).

Answer (score 0):

I think you still need at least one js file that you add using `api.add_files` from package.js, which you have it doing the `Npm.require`